# Count number of element in list by key using JQ

Tags: json, count, jq

I have the following JSON file content:

```
{ "a": ["2", "33", "ff"], "b": ["4", "aa", "555", "4445"], "c": ["a"] }
```

How can I get the size of the list of each key using `jq`, so that it outputs:

```
{"a": 3, "b": 4, "c": 1}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map_values`, it is like `map`, but works on objects too.

```
map_values(length)
```